# Weblogic: AppMerge failed to merge your application after Java 8 migration

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, web.xml

We are migrating Java EE application from *Java 6* to *Java 8*. This means the compile level and the migration from *Weblogic 11g on JRE6* to *Weblogic 12c on JRE8*.

When I try to deploy the project, I get the following error

```
<20.7.2017, 12:48:46,17 ip. EEST> <Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.> 
weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException: org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.handleStateChangeException(FlowDriver.java:55)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:38)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:146)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:159)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:116)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:158)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:94)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:58)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:186)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:160)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:777)
    at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow$2.execute(Flow.java:530)
    at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5646)
    at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.appSelected(Flow.java:528)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:262)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:134)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1129)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.internal.PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.strutsLookupInternal(PageFlowUtilsBeehiveDelegate.java:43)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.framework.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:108)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:707)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:141)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:108)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:399)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:465)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:291)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:219)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:275)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ParamFilter.doFilter(ParamFilter.java:38)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1026)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:493)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:470)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClassInternal(GenericClassLoader.java:1110)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1043)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1035)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:493)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:470)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.reflect.ReflectClassBuilder.populate(ReflectClassBuilder.java:110)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.elements.ClassImpl.ensureLoaded(ClassImpl.java:725)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.elements.ClassImpl.getInterfaces(ClassImpl.java:167)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.elements.ClassImpl.isAssignableFromRecursively(ClassImpl.java:684)
    at com.bea.util.jam.internal.elements.ClassImpl.isAssignableFrom(ClassImpl.java:270)
    at weblogic.wsee.jws.WebServiceRuntimeDecl.isProviderBasedEndpoint(WebServiceRuntimeDecl.java:127)
    at weblogic.wsee.jws.WebServiceRuntimeDecl.<init>(WebServiceRuntimeDecl.java:69)
    at weblogic.wsee.jws.WebServiceRuntimeDecl.<init>(WebServiceRuntimeDecl.java:60)
    at weblogic.wsee.jws.WebServiceRuntimeDecl.<init>(WebServiceRuntimeDecl.java:57)
    at weblogic.wsee.deploy.WSEEAnnotationProcessor.process(WSEEAnnotationProcessor.java:92)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.jws.jaxws.JAXWSAnnotationProcessor.process(JAXWSAnnotationProcessor.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.processAnnotations(WSEEModuleHelper.java:266)
    at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.processAnnotationsWithServiceLinks(WSEEModuleHelper.java:245)
    at weblogic.j2ee.wsee.compiler.WSEEModuleHelper.processAnnotations(WSEEModuleHelper.java:178)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.WSEEWebAppToolsModuleExtension.processAnnotations(WSEEWebAppToolsModuleExtension.java:216)
    at weblogic.wsee.tools.WSEEWebAppToolsModuleExtension.merge(WSEEWebAppToolsModuleExtension.java:109)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.MergeModuleFlow.compile(MergeModuleFlow.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.BaseMerger.merge(BaseMerger.java:20)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:75)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:40)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:37)
    ... 116 more
```

By a coincidence, I manged to make it deploy and run cleanly by updating *web.xml* schema from 2.3 to 3.1 and using `metadata-complete=true` attribute. But I don't understand the root cause of the problem, why this solution works, and could it have some unwanted side effects.

Comment: The missing class org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory is not provided by WebLogic Server. The Apache commons-pool lib is missing i think.