# Weblogic cannot deploy EAR due to appmerge failed

Tags: java, deployment, log4j, weblogic, ear

I would like to deploy EAR file to weblogic.
The original EAR was with log4j version 1, however now we are trying to upgrade it on higher version 2 due to vulnerability.

The original EAR can be deployed on weblogic with success.
But the fixed EAR with log4j2 (used via log4j bridge) cannot be deployed. There is below error occured.

Please any idea? :/ Thanks

```
Message icon - Error Unable to access the selected application.
Message icon - Error java.io.IOException
Message icon - Error weblogic.utils.compiler.ToolFailureException

 


In console there is error message like this:

<Error> <J2EE> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.>
```

**EDIT:**
I have tried to change attributes by updating web.xml schema from 2.3 to 3.1 and using metadata-complete=true. The deployment was fine :) however there was some next issue inside of weblogic - app is not in Active state. There in logs is something with weblogic.application.ModuleException.

Resource: [Weblogic: AppMerge failed to merge your application after Java 8 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45211729/weblogic-appmerge-failed-to-merge-your-application-after-java-8-migration)

Comment: Don't use Weblogic. I used to use it while I worked at Lockheed, and I absolutely hated it and so all other developers in my team. Of course, that was about 10-15 years ago, but managing Weblogic instances was always an absolute nightmare. Convince your management to switch to Tomcat or something else.

Comment: Understand. Thanks for advice. Therefore we are going to migrate the project into more smooth env. However, we are still using the apps on old env and need to resolve it.

Comment: Otherwise I have tried to change attributes by updating web.xml schema from 2.3 to 3.1 and using metadata-complete=true. And it worked well. However app is not in Active state that means there is some issue inside weblogic. I will edit my post about info.

Comment: I totally get it. We were stuck with Weblogic for similar reasons, but also because in a company like Lockheed with literally thousands of engineers, change comes very slow mostly because of familiarity. One thing I know is that Weblogic is super  heavy duty and even in a project like the F-35 where I worked for most of the 8.5 years I was there, you don't even use the server to its fullest potential. The side effect of that is situations like this... the problem might be simple, but no one knows how to solve it because the platform is so complicated.